# Why do I see a "Running" pod as "Failed" in Prometheus query result when the pod never failed?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

```
{__name__="kube_pod_status_phase",namespace="mynamespace",phase="Failed"}
```

When I run the aforementioned PromQL query, it also returns pods that have never failed (what I see in Kubernetes). The pod is in running status and has never failed or restarted. How is Prometheus marking it as "Failed"?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/568#issuecomment-442745590), the `kube_pod_status_phase` metric is an enum metric, and exposes a time-series for each possible state. However, only the one the Pod is in has the value of `1`.

So if you want to see actually `Failed` Pods, execute this query:

```
kube_pod_status_phase{namespace="mynamespace",phase="Failed"} == 1
```

Comment: This did the trick in Prometheus. Thank you. I now have to figure out how to make it work in Grafana to query with label_values.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think you need `label_values`. You can achieve this by using a `stat` panel with this query and using `{{ pod }}` in its legend to see Failed Pods (I didn't tested this, though).